# How to Generate QR Code Using ASP.NET with support UTF-8 (example support other languages than English)?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, qr-code

How to Generate QR Code Using ASP.NET with support UTF-8 (example support other languages than English) , Because I learn How to Generate QR Code Using ASP.NET with

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-generate-qr-code-using-asp-net

website but support only English language in QR Code , I have Generate QR Code Using ASP.NET with support UTF-8 (example support other languages than English).

Comment: Use a different library, note that some scanners might not be able to read such codes

Comment: Thanks you to answer , I change library of QRCoder to Zxing.net as web [link](https://github.com/ritesh9835/QrCode/tree/master/QRcodeDemo/QRcodeDemo) and add UTF-8 as web [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1005081/Basic-with-QR-Code-using-Zxing-Library) at Step 2: Coding in your Form Load and successful to support UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the [How to use QRCoder](https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder/wiki/How-to-use-QRCoder) documentation?

### Parameters of the CreateQrCode method

- Parameter name: forceUtf8
- Type: bool
- Default: false
- Description: This parameter enables you to force text encoding in UTF-8. By default (and as required by QR code ISO/IEC standard) text in Byte mode will be encoded in ISO-8859-1. Only if chars are detected, which can't be encoded in ISO-8859-1, QRCoder will switch to UTF-8.

The description should serve as a warning to you. Although you can encode UTF-8 data other QR code reading applications may not be prepared to accept it.

Comment: Thanks you to answer , I change library of QRCoder to Zxing.net as web [link](https://github.com/ritesh9835/QrCode/tree/master/QRcodeDemo/QRcodeDemo) and add UTF-8 as web [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1005081/Basic-with-QR-Code-using-Zxing-Library) at Step 2: Coding in your Form Load and successful to support UTF-8.